# How to read Date from textBox, having Jquery UI DatePicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

The below `Jquery UI Date Picker` shows the date in correct format, but reads it wrong.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="date">
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Show"/>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('#date').datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'});
$('#btn').click(function(){
  var _myDate = new Date($('#date').val());
  alert(_myDate);
});
```

Whats wrong? ( [Jsfiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Shahidiqbal390/YnESV/1/))

It shows the date correct, but reads it wrong...

When I use it like this:

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
      var _myDate = $('#date').val();
      alert(_myDate);
 });
```

It's ok, but when pass it to Server side using `C#` as string and then converting it to `DateTime` it gives me error of `Invalid Date` when every `Day` is selected greater than `12`. It treats with `Day` as a month. And my required format of Date is `dd/mm/yyyy`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**maybe this is your answer**

```
$( "#date" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy'});
    $('#btn').click(function(){
    var _myDate = new Date($('#date').val());
    var new_date=_myDate.split('-');
    var month=new_date[0];
    var day=new_date[1];
    var year=new_date[2];
    //you have 3 data, month, day and year.

    alert(month+"/"+day+"/"+year);
    });
```

you can use that 3 variable **day, month, year** to write your programs

Comment: Your welcome and god bless you. don't forget to press the green tick to say this is the true answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Change var `_myDate = new Date($('#date').val()  );` to var `_myDate = $('#date').val());`

Comment: Have you tested your suggestion in Shahid's [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Shahidiqbal390/YnESV/1/)?

Comment: @Matt Yes I have tested for his original post, which didn't have the server side section !

Comment: I see, that is the part I was missing. So you suggest to pass the value 'as is' and do the conversion on the server using c# / .net library conversions, right?

Comment: @Matt No! I wouldn't suggest that.Actually, I was intending to post the whole solution, but I realized that Kermani had nearly done that. Hence, I didn't do. To post a culture-agnostic date value to server, the author should use the yyyy-mm-dd format.By doing that way, the server side code would work fine .

Comment: I agree, and if it is a international application the UTC offset should be sent along as well. So ISO date/time format is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
$( "#date" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy'});
$('#btn').click(function(){
var _myDate = new Date($('#date').val()  );
alert(_myDate);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/YnESV/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the Date type declaration - you can just do

```
$( "#date" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'});
$('#btn').click(function(){
  var _myDate = $('#date').val();
alert(_myDate);
});
```

Javascript is a dynamically typed language so the Date initialisation is unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

**Try this: it's work fine**

```
  $('#date').datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',  changeMonth:true, changeYear:true,showOn: "both",buttonImage: "",buttonImageOnly: false });

console.log($('#date').val());
```

Comment: In Console it works fine, but on server side its invalid date, when day is greater than 12 like `13-03-14`.

Answer (score 0):

My javaScript function...

```
convertDate = function (strDate) {
   var newDate = new Date();
   var oldDate = '';
   if (strDate.contains('/')) {
         oldDate = strDate.split('/');
      } else if (strDate.contains('-')) {
         oldDate = strDate.split('-');
      }
     //OldDate format is dd/mm/yyyy
      newDate.setDate(oldDate[0]);
      newDate.setMonth(oldDate[1] - 1);
      newDate.setYear(oldDate[2]);
      return newDate;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just parse the textbox value using `parseDate` with the same format you initially set up the datepicker:

```
console.log($.datepicker.parseDate("dd-mm-yy", $('#date').val()));
```

parseDate will return a Date object so that you don't need to create it manually.